# How can I create an SVG file from the content of a UITextView in iOS (Objective-C)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg, svgkit

I'm aware of this SVGKit, but it seems that its primary use is for rendering existing SVG files. Is there a way I can use it or anything else to generate an SVG from a UITextView and/or programmatically create an SVG from scratch in Objective C?

Comment: Does it have to be SVG? Would PDF be ok?

Comment: I need to add an SVG to a UIImage and then export the whole thing as a single PNG...

Comment: “add an SVG to a UIImage” implies you want to import an SVG file, not generate an SVG file. I don't understand.

Comment: I want to take what the user created in a single UITextView (text, font family, font color, font size), and generate an SVG that exactly replicates what was contained inside that UITextView so that I can scale up the SVG to a size many times greater than the original UITextView so that it can be sent to print on a large surface. I have attempted to simply scale up the font size and create a second much larger UITextView, but in doing so, there are certain critical points where the font size may cause unintended word wrappings onto the next line, which destroys the original layout made by user.

Comment: And your print service only accepts SVG, not PDF? iOS has built-in support for generating PDFs.

Comment: I have to be able to lay the scaled up text on top of a photo and then export the whole thing as a PNG with a transparent background. I know how to export a UIView as a PNG, but I want to avoid the aforementioned problems with scaling up the font. If a PDF is scalable and can be saved with a transparent background, then placed on top of a photo (UIImage), and all exported as a PNG... then that might work.

Comment: And you want to do all of this compositing on an iOS device? How big (in pixels) do you want the final exported PNG?

Comment: Yes. That's the purpose of the app. User creates text/image content, sends to printer. 1008 x 1152 pixels... or 14" x 16". I'm looking into the PDF option. That might work.